# Reinstall Ubuntu on remote machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, virtual-machine, vps

I have been renting VPS from provider that no longer offers servers in location I am interested with. This machine has Ubuntu 14.04 installed which was upgraded to 16.04. It was in heavy use which led to a lot of no longer needed packages, services and messed up configurations.

I would like to clean it up as it is necessary since getting a new one is not an option for the reason mentioned above. It would be a lot of work and I would probably miss a thing or two so it would be great if I just could reinstall Ubuntu.

I cannot do it from administrator panel and uploading own image is not possible.
Does Ubuntu include similar feature to Windows, where you can do factory reset?

Comment: So you want to remove all users and start "clean"? Without a reinstallation from the ISO image, your only option would be to login as root and remove all users, then clean the /home directory. This would be about as clean as you could get but would not have any effect on installed applications, binaries and other files the system uses. There is no "reset" or restore to stock that I am aware of in Ubuntu or most Linux distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I hope to remove all modifications done to the system including unnecessary applications and changes in configuration. I was thinking of something like resizing disk, installing another system, chrooting into it, reinstalling Ubuntu, logging into new system, deleting old one and resizing again. I don't know if it is possible on remote machine where I cannot edit boot file and still be able to start system. I still hope for option to do it using Ubuntu's internal functionalities.

Comment: Perhaps... Can you roughly duplicate the virtual environment locally? You might be able to do a clean install into a local VM, `dd` the image and transfer it over, resize the disk and then `dd` it out to the new partition, then edit GRUB to boot into the new machine and reboot. Problem is if anything fails, you will have no choice to engage the VM hosting company to get access to it again, which sounds like a "difficult" thing to do. TBH, if you are still renting space they should support you. If not, I would find a new provider to host your VM.